# NodeJs express.Router resolves to wrong path

Tags: node.js, express

I have a router setup like below:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const controller = require('../../module/controllers/controller');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/:param', controller.getEntity);
router.get('/', controller.getEntities);
router.put('/:param', controller.updateEntity);
router.post('/update/:param', controller.updateEntity);
router.get('/subpath', controller.getEntityPath);

module.exports = router;
```

All the above routes have a parent route: `parent`

When I try to call `http://hostname/parent/subpath` it keeps going to `http://hostname/parent/`. Only when I comment out the below lines, `subpath` becomes available:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const controller = require('../../module/controllers/controller');

const router = express.Router();

// router.get('/:param', controller.getEntity);
// router.get('/', controller.getEntities);
router.put('/:param', controller.updateEntity);
router.post('/update/:param', controller.updateEntity);
router.get('/subpath', controller.getEntityPath);

module.exports = router;
```

What am I doing wrong in the configuration?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to reverse the order of the routes :

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const controller = require('../../module/controllers/controller');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', controller.getEntities);
router.post('/update/:param', controller.updateEntity);
router.get('/subpath', controller.getEntityPath);
router.get('/:param', controller.getEntity);
router.put('/:param', controller.updateEntity);
module.exports = router;
```

Because `http://hostname/parent/subpath` matches `/:param` first.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put absolute routes above the relative routes.

```
router.post('/update/:param', controller.updateEntity);
router.get('/subpath', controller.getEntityPath);    
router.put('/:param', controller.updateEntity);
```